# Why this numpy for statement give me wrong vlaues?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

below code give me

0.1

0.2

0.30000000000000004

0.4

0.5

0.6

0.7000000000000001

0.8

0.9

1.0

and I don't know why 0.3 and 0.7 come out that way.

```py
import numpy as np

for i in np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [the docs for `np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not
> be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.